# Highcharts - Change line color between points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a line chart graph as can be seen on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qjmjd34d/5/

And with this code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            color: 'purple'
        }
    },

    series: [{
    data: [{x: 1, y: 435, color:'blue'},
           {x: 2, y: 437, color:'blue'}, 
           {x: 3, y: 455, color:'blue'}, 
           {x: 4, y: 475, color:'blue'}, 
           {x: 5, y: 555, color:'blue'},
           {x: 6, y: 435, color:'blue'}]
    }]
});
```

Modifying the color of the points is oblivious however, how is it possible to change the color of the line between them?

Suppose I want the line in the given example on the fiddle to be green only between x = 3 and x = 5 -  how is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To color part of the graph, you can use `zones`.

If you include this in the series you have above it will color 3 to 5 red.

```
zoneAxis: 'x',
zones: [{value: 3}, {value: 5, color: 'red'}]
```

Zones work by coloring **up to** `value`. That means that we have to make one element with value 3 and no color to pass on whatever color is set elsewhere. The element with value 5 will therefore color from 3 to 5.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qjmjd34d/6/

**API on series.line.zones:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

Comment: Can we change specific value point color in line chart, instead of changing the line color ?