# Highcharts - Add Point to chart with different color based on some condition dynamically

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, colors, point

everyone ! I;m working on a Highchart where it appends values to the chart for every 5 seconds time. I'm adding points like this,

```
series.addPoint([(new Date()).getTime(), xnum(n.PointValue)], true, true);
```

When adding a point I want to add the point with a different color (RED) based on some other property. Can anyone help me to add the point with a different color ? Thanks

Comment: What type of chart? Is it line? Bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the color directly while adding a new point. Instead of array try using an object with a property 'color'.

```
series.addPoint({
y:(new Date()).getTime(), 
x:xnum(n.PointValue), 
color:some_condition?'red': 'blue'},
true, true);
```

An example pen
https://codepen.io/samuellawrentz/pen/XYVBjR?editors=1010

Comment: Beat me to it! Do note that this will only color the actual point red, if you want to color a line red, you need to use zones like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533162/highcharts-change-line-color-between-points/47533303#47533303