# How Change color of line graph in Highchart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have to create line graph like the below image. When Actual value exceeding Plan value line color should be green otherwise line color should be red in same line graph using below value

```
lstMonth : Array(48) 0 : Actual : "74" Chart_Code : "SACL\S&M\Over All\R0" From : null GraphModel : null GraphTitle : "Overall Achievement " GraphType : "" Graph_Better : "1" Graph_Better2 : "0" Id : null Last_Year_Actual : "99" Month : "Apr" PageNo : "3" Plan : "100" Plan_revised : "" Policy_Ref_No : "OverAll" Responsible : "SL" Revision_No : "0" ScissorType : "0" To : null UOM : "%" Variance : "" pagetitle : null [[Prototype]] : Object 1 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'May', Plan: '100', …} 2 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Jun', Plan: '100', …} 3 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Jul', Plan: '100', …} 4 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Aug', Plan: '100', …} 5 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Sep', Plan: '100', …} 6 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Oct', Plan: '100', …} 7 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Nov', Plan: '100', …} 8 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Dec', Plan: '100', …} 9 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Jan', Plan: '100', …} 10 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Feb', Plan: '100', …} 11 : {Id: null, Policy_Ref_No: 'OverAll', Chart_Code: 'SACL\S&M\Over All\R0', Month: 'Mar', Plan: '100', …}
```

[image: Sample Chart]

Comment: @Hermanboxcar Please check this now

Comment: Use the ```color``` property in the ```plotOptions``` or directly in the ```series``` object, so it looks like ```color: parseInt(item.Actual) > parseInt(item.Plan) ? 'green' : 'red'```

Comment: I have to change Line color, not datapoint color. While doing like this, I can change Datapoint color. @Keyboard Corporation

Comment: highcharts does not directly support changing the color of a line segment based on its value, but you can use [zones](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones) you can also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47533162/highcharts-change-line-color-between-points)

Comment: But I cannot use zones, because Plan value will varries every time. Any other possible way to get chart like this? @Keyboard Corporation

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically calculate zones based on your data. For example:

```
const processedData = data.map(dataEl => [dataEl.Motnh, +dataEl.ActualValue]);
const zones = data.map((dataEl, index) => ({
  value: index,
  color: +dataEl.ActualValue > +dataEl.Plan ? 'green' : 'red'
}));

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category'
  },
  series: [{
    zoneAxis: 'x',
    data: processedData,
    zones
  }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/foLx4vd1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

Comment: Thank You @ppotaczek, In this case I'm getting chart with color code. But my actual requirement is not this. Like that image I have shared with this question. When Actual value exceeding Plan value, From blue color to next datapoint green color else red color. Please give me solution for this requirement.

Comment: Hi @Edwin K Biju, I'm sorry but I don't quite understand. When exactly the color should be blue?